# Struct Array Indexes not being filled after first index

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, struct, fstream

I have an input file with 3 fields on each line that are type: string, double, double. There are 15 lines with data.

The format of the input file data is:

Katmandu,    -34,   28 
cityName,    lowTemp,   highTemp 
.... 
...  
..

It's obvious that it's not getting the 3rd input on the line, based on the output.

Here is the code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 15; index++)
    {
        getline(inFile, weatherInfo[index].city, ',');
        inFile >> weatherInfo[index].low >> weatherInfo[index].high;
        inFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');   
    }
```

For some reason this is my output:

```
Katmandu (-34, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
```

I know my program is able to read the other lines because when I add

```
inFile.ignore(20);
```

to the beginning of my statement it the loop it outputs

```
28
Perth (92, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
```

Output Code:

```
void ShowAll(int count)                                         //Show entire data function
{

int x = 0;                                                  //loop through the index of city[], lowTemp[], highTemp[], and print them.
while (x < count)
{
    cout << weatherInfo[x].city << " (" << weatherInfo[x].low << ", " << weatherInfo[x].high << ")" << endl;

    x++;

}

cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Show how the data is stored in the input file.

Comment: Done, sorry that I didn't originally

Comment: Maybe problem is with printing, not reading?

Comment: Probably having the output printing code here would be useful as well.

Comment: output printing code added @Rush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data in a line are separated by commas then you should use the following approach

```
#include <sstream>

//...

std::string line;

for ( int index = 0; index < 15 && std::getline( inFile, line ); index++)
{
    std::istringstream is( line );

    getline( is, weatherInfo[index].city, ',');

    std::string field;
    if ( getline( is, field, ',') ) weatherInfo[index].low = std::stod( field );
    if ( getline( is, field, ',') ) weatherInfo[index].high = std::stod( field );
}
```

The problem with your code is that an error occurs when you are trying to read double values and a comma is encountered. In this case ths state of the stream will be erroneous and all other input will be ignored.

Also you should check what is the point representation for doubles in the locale you are using.

Comment: Wow that did it. Thank you! This is my second c++ and I'v never seen code written in the manner.